# What is a field?

Tags: java, class, variables, field

In the Oracle tutorials, it reads:

"To access a field, you can use a named reference to an object, as in the previous examples, or you can use any expression that returns an object reference."

Given that 'field' is another name for a 'class variable'; why would you use a 'named reference to an object' ?  Surely it would be better to use a 'named reference to a class' ?

A rewrite would look like this:
"To access a class variable, you can use a named reference to an object, as in the previous examples, or you can use any expression that returns an object reference."

Surely a 'named reference to an object' would be used to access an 'object variable' and not a 'class variable' ?

Comment: Could you add a link to a specific part of the tutorial with the definitions you quote? The wording you cite is close to the spec: `Field declarations (§8.3) describe class variables, which are incarnated once, and instance variables, which are freshly incarnated for each instance of the class. A field may be declared final (§8.3.1.2), in which case it can be assigned to only once. Any field declaration may include an initializer.` But it clearly states that a field can _also_ be an instance variable. From: [Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html)

Comment: what is your question? or you want to show how smart you are by rephrasing java tutorials?

Comment: Sure zrvan.  Here is the page in question:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html

It is the 18th line.

Comment: @Chris, ah, but your assumption that `field` is another name for `class variable` is wrong, the tutorial at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) at least clearly differentiate, following the spec that I quoted earlier, between class variable fields (with the static modifier) and instance variable fields (without). Any instance variable field (which is also a class member field) must be accessed through a reference to an instance of the class (and must have the public modifier).

Comment: Yes I understand that there are differences between a 'class variable field' and and 'instance variable field'.

However, aren't the terms 'field' and 'variable' the same thing ?

Answer (score 0):

I interpret "named reference to an object" as "variable".  Here's the definition of `field` in [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/information/glossary.html):

> A data member of a class. Unless specified otherwise, a field is not static.

So in the following example, `book` is a variable (a "named reference to an object", `books[0]` is an "expression that returns a reference", and `Title` is a "field":

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title;
}

Book book = new Book();
book.Title = "Moby Dick";  // set field value

Book[] books = new Book[10];
books[0] = book;

string title = books[0].Title;  // expression that returns an object reference.
```

Answer (score -1):

> Given that 'field' is another name for a 'class variable'; why would you use a 'named reference to an object' ? Surely it would be better to use a 'named reference to a class' ?

I don't know if the tutorial actually states this, but in any case this is wrong. The Java Language Specification clearly states (emphasis mine):

> Field declarations (§8.3) describe class variables, which are incarnated once, and *instance variables, which are freshly incarnated for each instance of the class.*

Accessing and or modifying these *instance variables*, which are freshly incarnated for each object through a named reference or an expression that returns a reference to an object thus makes perfect sense.

If the tutorial indeed states something contradicting this, it is incorrect.